# How to iterate through table rows and cells in Javascript to get the Input and Dropdown values?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input

[image]    So I have this HTML table
I am trying to get all the values from the columns with a mix of input boxes and drop downs. When I try the double loop method it works but returns null in all the containers.
I than created a loop to get all the values, but this solution comes with two problems. One I can't use this for a sql query because it does it one by one and the table is not static. Sometimes it can have two rows or twenty roles so getting getInput[i].value does me no good because I can't hard code getInput[2].value, getInput[4].value, etc. The second issue I can't combine this loop with the previous because than it becomes too nested and it causes other variables to not be readable. The goal is to get all the values from let say OBJ_TYPE column and store them into a row so that when it gets inserted into the DB it insert all the rows with all the data. So when I log the data OBJ_NAME should return 1,4 Project2,5 etc etc.

```
    $(document).on("click", "#devSaveBtn", function () {
      var answer = window.confirm("Save changes");
      if (answer) {
        var getInput = document.querySelectorAll(".vcheck");
        for (var i = 0; i < getInput.length; i++)
          console.log(getInput[i].id, " => Input", i, " = ", getInput[i].value);

        var table = document.getElementById("steptable");
        for (var i = 0, row; (row = table.rows[i]); i++) {
          // * iterate through rows
          // * rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
          for (var j = 0, col; (col = row.cells[j]); j++) {
            // * iterate through columns
            // * columns would be accessed using the "col" variable assigned in the for loop
            var ObjType = [table.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML];
            var Name = [table.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML];
            var Business = [table.rows[i].cells[4].innerHTML];
            var Project = [table.rows[i].cells[5].innerHTML];
            var Deployer_Candidate = [table.rows[i].cells[6].innerHTML];
            var Description = [table.rows[i].cells[7].innerHTML];
            console.log(ObjType.innerHTML, col.innerHTML);
          }
        }

      // * else display service message
      else {
        console.log("Service Cancel");
      }
    });
          <!-- * Main Record Table *-->
                        <div id="steptablecontainer">
                            <div id="steptable_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper no-footer">
                                <table id="steptable" class="compact cell-border no-footer dataTable row-border"
                                    role="grid">
                                    <thead id="recordTableHead">
                                        <tr role="row">
                                            <!-- * Names For Each Container *-->
                                            <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                                aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label=""
                                                style="width: 25px; max-width: 25px;"></th>
                                            <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                                aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label=""
                                                style="width: 50px; background-image: none; max-width: 25px;">Record</th>
                                            <th class="componentellipsis sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                                aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Component"
                                                style="width: 200px; max-width: 50px;">Type</th>
                                            <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                                aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Type"
                                                style="width: 125px;">Name</th>
                                            <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                                aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Test"
                                                style="width: 100px; max-width: 50px;">Business</th>
                                            <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                                aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Dev"
                                                style="width: 200px; max-width: 50px;">Project</th>
                                            <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                                aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Type"
                                                style="width: 150px; max-width: 125px;">Deployer Candidate</th>
                                            <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                                aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Type"
                                                style="width: 400px; max-width: 200px; overflow: hidden;">Description
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>

                                    <!-- * Sample Record (Cloned then changed) *-->
                                    <tbody id="recordRow0" style="display:none; border: 10px;" class="recordRow">
                                        <tr role="row" class="" data-true-step="1">
                                            <td class="noncomponentswidth">
                                                <button class="readyonlyhidden" id="removeRecordBtn0" title="Remove Record"
                                                    value="0">
                                                    <span><i style="font-size:18px;" class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></span>
                                                </button>
                                            </td>
                                            <!-- * Record intializing *-->
                                            <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordCount">1</td>


                                            <!-- * Drop down for the obj_type *-->
                                            <div id="container">
                                                <td class="componentellipsis" id="recordTypeWrapper">
                                                    <select id="OBJ_TYPE" class="vcheck">
                                                        <option value="TP">TP</option>
                                                        <option value="Workflow">Workflow</option>
                                                        <option value="Package">Package</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </td>
                                            </div>


                                            <!-- * Container for Obj Name *-->
                                            <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordObjName">
                                                <p>
                                                    <!-- * Input for Obj Name *-->
                                                    <input type="text" id="OBJ_NAME" name="Object Name" placeholder=""
                                                        class="vcheck" required minlength="8">
                                                </p>
                                            </td>

                                            <!-- * Deployer Business *-->
                                            <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordDevName">
                                                <input type="text" id="DEPLOYER_BUSINESS" name="Business Name"
                                                    placeholder="" style="display: none;">
                                                <select id="DEPLOYER_BUSINESS" class="vcheck">
                                                    <!-- * Picklist for TP *-->
                                                    <option value="APPM">APPM</option>
                                                    <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
                                                    <option value="CorporateAP">CorporateAP</option>
                                                    <option value="CorporateCredit">CorporateCredit</option>
                                                    <option value="CorporateEHS">CorporateEHS</option>
                                                    <option value="CorporateFinance">CorporateFinance</option>
                                                    <option value="CorporateFinancialServices">CorporateFinancialServices
                                                    </option>
                                                    <option value="CorporateHR">CorporateHR</option>
                                                    <option value="CorporateIT">CorporateIT</option>
                                                    <option value="CorporateLegal">CorporateLegal</option>
                                                    <option value="CorporateLogistics">CorporateLogistics</option>
                                                    <option value="CorporateTax">CorporateTax</option>
                                                    <option value="EMEAPackaging">EMEAPackaging</option>
                                                    <option value="EMEAPapers">EMEAPapers</option>
                                                    <option value="GCF">GCF</option>
                                                    <option value="MillManufacturing">MillManufacturing</option>
                                                    <option value="MillSupport">MillSupport</option>
                                                    <option value="NAIPGContainer">NAIPGContainer</option>
                                                    <option value="NAIPGContainerboard">NAIPGContainerboard</option>
                                                    <option value="NAIPGRecycling">NAIPGRecycling</option>
                                                    <option value="NAP">NAP</option>
                                                    <option value="SouthAmerica">SouthAmerica</option>
                                                    <option value="zConnectivity">zConnectivity</option>
                                                    <option value="zSylvamo">zSylvamo</option>
                                                </select>

                                            </td>

                                            <!-- * Input for Deployer Project *-->
                                            <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordProjectName">
                                                <input type="text" id="DEPLOYER_PROJECT" name="Project Name" class="vcheck"
                                                    placeholder="">
                                            </td>


                                            <!-- * Deployer_Candidate *-->
                                            <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="titleDeployerCandidate">
                                                <select id="DEPLOYER_CANDIDATE" class="vcheck">

                                                    <!-- * Picklist for TP *-->
                                                    <option value="PRODJ (wm53a/b/c 10000)">PRODJ (wm53a/b/c 10000)
                                                    </option>
                                                    <option value="PRODR (wm53a/b/c 12000)">PRODR (wm53a/b/c 12000)
                                                    </option>
                                                    <option value="PRODXA (wm54a/b/c 21000)">PRODXA (wm54a/b/c
                                                        21000)
                                                    </option>
                                                    <option value="PRODXS (wm54a/b/c 20000)">PRODXS (wm54a/b/c
                                                        20000)
                                                    </option>
                                                    <option value="PRODXE (wm53a/b/c 11000)">PRODXE (wm53a/b/c
                                                        11000)
                                                    </option>
                                                    <option value="-------------------">-------------------</option>
                                                    <option value="PRODAD1 (wm54a/b/c 60000)">PRODAD1 (wm54a/b/c 60000)
                                                    </option>
                                                    <option value="PRODAD2 (wm54a/b/c 61000)">PRODAD2 (wm54a/b/c 61000)
                                                    </option>
                                                    <option value="-------------------">-------------------</option>
                                                    <option value="MAPGRP1 (wm52a/b/c 40k/41k/42k)">MAPGRP1
                                                        (wm52a/b/c
                                                        40k/41k/42k)</option>
                                                </select>

                                            </td>

                                            <!-- * Input for Description *-->
                                            <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordDeployerCandidate" placeholder="">
                                                <input type="text" id="DESCRIPTION" name="Description" placeholder=""
                                                    class="vcheck" style="resize: vertical; width: 100%; height: 4.5em;"
                                                    </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>

                                <!-- * Add & Remove buttons *-->
                                <div class="btn-group2">
                                    <div id="addRemoveButons" class="dt-buttons" style="visibility:hidden">
                                        <button class="readonlyhidden" tabindex="0" aria-controls="steptable" type="button"
                                            id="recordAddBtn2" title="Add new record" style="display: inline-block;">
                                            <span><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></span>
                                        </button>
                                        <button class="readonlyhidden" tabindex="0" aria-controls="steptable" type="button"
                                            id="recordAddBtn" title="Add new record">
                                            <span><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></span>
                                        </button>
                                        <button class="readonlyhidden" tabindex="0" aria-controls="steptable" type="button"
                                            id="recordRemoveBtn" title="Remove last record" style="display: none">
                                            <span><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></span>
                                        </button>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what the expected result is.

Comment: The expected result is that If I have multiple rows in the table if wherever I type in the values of the columns it log every instance and if I needed to store that value in a variable and insert it into a DB it be easier.

Comment: Maybe this will be of help to you: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/5yxgb13c/

Comment: Holy cow. That is a lot less code and seems to do exact same thing. Thank you there only one part missing though to make this perfect, how would I get a particular value and use that in a sql update statement? Since there no variable defining the column name.

Comment: So if I have       DB("UPDATE TABLE SET OBJ_NAME = '" + Name + "', OBJ_TYPE = '" + ObjType + "', DEPLOYER_BUSINESS = '" + Business + "', DEPLOYER_CANDIDATE = '" + Deployer_Candidate + "', DEPLOYER_PROJECT = '" + Project + "', DESCRIPTION = '" + Description + "' WHERE TICKET_NUM = '" + selectTkt.value + "'"); Is there a way to do that? https://imgur.com/a/i0nzwYW So in my sql query it update both rows without hard coding the exact index of where it was in the array?

Comment: It's not clear to me how you wish to determine _which_ row you are going to use for your SQL statement. Regardless, I would create serialized form data from the inputs in the row. See: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/b76c8n0g/. And do be sure to escape your values on the server to prevent SQL injection: https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection